# LSTM Time Series Forecasting with TimeSeries_Generator

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, lstm, forecasting

I am new to using LSTM for time series forecasting.
I want to forecast future call arrivals and my data has 19 explanatory variables and one dependent variable (call arrivals). One day consists of 30 observations; one week consists of 180 observations.

I replaced nominal variables with numerical values, normalized the data and splitted it into training and test (Please ignore the 1's*180; I want to replace the 1's later with a for-loop (for i in 52) since i want to predict 52 times 180 observations (one week))

```
data_LSTM_matrix <- data.matrix(data_LSTM)
train_data <- data_LSTM_matrix[1:(21090+(1*180)),]
mean <- apply(train_data, 2, mean)
std <- apply(train_data, 2, sd)
data_normalized <- scale(data_LSTM_matrix, center = mean, scale = std)

train_y<-as.numeric(data_normalized[1:(21090+(1*180)),20])
train_x<-as.matrix(data_normalized[1:(21090+(1*180)),c(1:19)])
test_y<-as.numeric(data_normalized[(21631+(1*180)):(21631+((1+1)*180)),20])
test_x<-as.matrix(data_normalized[(21631+(1*180)):(21631+((1+1)*180)),c(1:19)])
```

Then I used keras' timeseries_generator(). As stated earlier, I want to predict 180 half-hour intervals, i.e., one week:

```
train_data_gen<-timeseries_generator(train_x,train_y,length=180, sampling_rate=1, stride=1, batch_size=30)
test_data_gen<-timeseries_generator(test_x,test_y,length=180, sampling_rate=1, stride=1, batch_size=180)
```

My Model looks like this:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_lstm(units = 128, dropout = 0.4, recurrent_dropout = 0.4,
             return_sequences = TRUE,
             input_shape = c(180,19)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1)

model %>% compile(
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
  loss = "mae"
)

history <- model %>% fit_generator(
  train_data_gen,
  epochs = 30,
  steps_per_epoch=5,
  verbose=2
)
```

And my predictions are generated like this:

```
testpredict<-predict_generator(model, test_data_gen, steps=1)
```

However, my predictions are really bad (after inverting the normalization) and are of shape [1,1:180,1]; I am wondering if it even forecasts the call arrivals.

These are my questions:
1. Are my timeseries_generators() correctly defined? I wonder whether I really have to put 180 in the length argument. Is it only considering 180 past_timesteps then and not the whole training set?
2. Is the shape of the output ([1,1:180,1]) correct? I expected to get a vector.

Comment: Your model outputs shape is (1, 180, 1) because of the return_sequences=True parameter, if you want to predict a vector of size e.g., 5 you can set the return_sequences parameter to False and put the desired output sequence length in the dense layer. model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, input_shape=(180, 19)))
model.add(layers.Dense(5)) Take a look to this tutorial: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-multi-step-time-series-forecasting-of-household-power-consumption/

Comment: Thank you so much! And is the argument length=180 in the timeseries_generator() correctly defined?

Comment: Is correctly defined as you want to use 180 steps as input for the prediction. However, as far as I know Keras TimeSeriesGenerator is limited to one-step-ahead forecasting so for multiple-steps-ahead forecasting you could try to create your own generator or use another kind of function. A good startpoint for time series LSTM forecasting is the machinelearningmastery tutorials. Check the function to_supervised in https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-multi-step-time-series-forecasting-of-household-power-consumption/ to prepare your data for multi-step forecasting